# Keras: Multi-label classification with U-net architcture for effective background/foreground image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a series of cell images (+ masks) similar to 'D' in the following picture:

[image]

However, I'm trying to set up a two-label classification network using the Unet architecture where I explicitly label the following two components of an image:

1) The Cells, and

2) The Background (or the borders of cells)

My reasoning for having a dedicated label for the background is as follows: my original images are 2000x3000 in size, and I want to chunk the images into the Unet as 512x512 blocks. However, when training the original Unet in this manner, I find that because a fair amount of the 512x512 blocks don't contain any cells (they're mostly Background, so the accompanying masks are empty), the loss for every epoch hovers at 0.4 and the network has a lot of trouble training. This is in spite of the presence of good 512x512 blocks that do contain good cell + mask layers.

My thinking is that, to get the Unet system to work with 2 labels and segment the images properly, I need to provide two things:
1) Another set of masks for the background itself so the network can positively identify the background.
2) An output modifier for the Unet Keras code itself so it gives out 2 labels instead of one.

However, please correct me if I am wrong on 1 assumption: the Unet architecture will work better to segment images if provided with a series of negative controls (background) as well as positive controls (the cells).

Here's the Keras Model based off [the Kaggle starter tutorial model](https://www.kaggle.com/keegil/keras-u-net-starter-lb-0-277):

```
inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (s)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_iou])
    model.summary()
```

**1) Getting the Unet to output 2 labels:**

Should I change the output layer from

```
outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
```

to:

```
outputs = Conv2D(2, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
```

**2) How do I structure the input array for the masks**

For the mask labels, I have a 3D numpy array in the shape of: `(# images, height, width)` with `dtype=uint8`. Every mask is binarised to 0 or 255 for a single label (eg the cell). Do I create another mask array with the same shape and pass that into the network as another training layer, or do I label the background as a separate number in the original mask image? To simplify: how do I train 2 types of labels in the Unet architecture?

**EDIT:**

This is the code for my loss metric. It's a combination between dice coefficient and binary crossentropy:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def bce_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 0.5 * binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: You use 0-255 for sigmoid? That a bit strange, maybe the cause of problem is this?

Comment: Good spotting, I didn't consider changing that. Would you recommend a `relu` instead?

Comment: I think you should use 0-1 and sigmoid.

Comment: Oh I see, so to normalise the data first. I'll give that a go. What do you think about the idea of labeling the background in addition to the cell structures?

Comment: Well, the bg is just 1-foreground right? It's just a binary problem for foreground and background so I doubt it would be any different.

Comment: Not quite - the input images look a bit like the bottom two in the following picture: https://www.essenbioscience.com/media/uploads/files/fig-2.jpg The background is messy and often at a gradient from very dark to slightly grey. If I could mask the background and have a separate mask for the foreground, I hope to better segment the two. Better example - D in the following: https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/advances/4/4/eaas8998/F1.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1

Comment: I mean, the mask you want is gradient? That's another strange point. But if that's the case then multiclass makes more sense to me. But if you just want to tell is it a cell or bg in this area then I think it's not much difference. You should try both though.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make myself clear. I want to implement negative controls - if I can get the network to know that dubious ares (like the gray fuzzy regions in image D of my post) actually belong to class X (which is noise) instead of not belonging to the foreground, then the network might train better. This is because currently, I'm feeding a lot of 'background' images into the network (these are unlabelled) but not sure if this is helping train the foreground segmentation.  If I were to go down this route, could you show me how to input two types of masks into the network?

Comment: Or, let's say that I want to add a second feature where I add the border of the cell as a distinct label to improve border segregation - could you show me how to use two labels?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue, and what loss function are you using?

Comment: Hi @Kalpit - I've edited my post to include the loss metric. Looking back on this question, I originally wanted a way to help the Keras U-net model to process chunks of larger images (512x512 squares of a 2x3k image, with some overflow). I was having trouble getting the train to push beyond a loss ceiling; resulting mask generation was very poor. Scaling the original image down to 1024x1024 gives much much better results but I lose some segmentation between close cells, so I wanted a way to 'zoom in' and give the network more information. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm having similar issues, and I actually ended up using a similar loss function. I found that labeling background actually gave me worse results with using plain BCE, as U-Net quickly converged to classifying all pixels as background and didn't budge because of high class imbalance in my case.

Comment: That's really interesting @Kalpit. I suppose the single label already has the background built into the classification in a negative sense, but it's interesting that the second classification doesn't help differentiate the foreground/background. Do you have any thoughts on processing a large image in chunks, or another way to handle larger data?

Comment: I might be able to help. How do we get in touch?